# Default.aspx redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a default.aspx page like this with the goal of redirecting differently based on the host header.

```
<%
if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host == "xxx.xxx.com")
{
response.redirect ("place/subplace/xxx.aspx")
}
else
{
response.redirect ("place/xxx.aspx")
}
%>
```

but it is giving me the error "Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# expressions are terminated with a semicolon `;`

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host == "xxx.xxx.com")
{
    Response.Redirect("place/subplace/xxx.aspx"); <-- here
} 
else
{
    Response.Redirect("place/xxx.aspx"); <-- and here
}
```

and C# is case-sensitive. Both `Response` and `Redirect` start with a capital letter.

**Edit:** Since you now tagged this as VB.Net

Your code is no valid VB.net code. If it were it should read like the following:

```
If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host = "xxx.xxx.com" Then
    Response.Redirect("place/subplace/xxx.aspx")
Else
    Response.Redirect("place/xxx.aspx")
End If
```

Comment: No this is not correct. If I remove the if statement the redirects work with or without the semicolon. With the if statement I get the error, which is on line 2 (same line as the if statement)

Comment: It's something to do with the host value and the comparison

Comment: It might looking for VB code, which could be the problem.  Would this be written differently in VB?

Comment: and I didn't tag it as C# to begin with I guess an admin did that. Really wasn't sure what kind of code I needed to use since there was no solution or codebehind involved.

Comment: I tagged it C# since the code in your question looks like C#, not VB.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler gives the error "expression expected" , it's usually a synthax error. Add a semi-column(;) after response.redirect?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host == "xxx.xxx.com")
        {
            Response.Redirect("place/subplace/xxx.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("place/xxx.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I use that I get the error "BC30205: End of statement expected.
" pointing to the very first line. Is this meant to on an aspx page between <% %> tags?

Comment: No you don't. As stated in my answer above you need the semicolons (even if you think you know better). And your use of `response.redirect` probably won't compile either.

Comment: I don't think I know better, do you really think I wouldn't try it before telling you it doesn't work? I have the exact code posted above in place and am getting the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_redirect.asp

Using the above link, I wrote the following lines and it executed without any problem. Notice there is no semicolon at the end. My default.aspx page just contains the following three lines.

```
<%
    Response.Redirect("~/portal")
%>
```

Possible reason is; usually language is mentioned at the top of .aspx pages or in the web.config file. If language is not mentioned, IIS uses VB.NET to compile the pages and we know that VB.NET doesn't uses semicolons to terminate the statements.